# get user email from google plus using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-plus, google-oauth

I want to access user email.In my scope i have entered `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` but it does not returns me user mail.

My code:

```
FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id=client id,
        client_secret=client secret,
        scope=('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','https://mail.google.com/'),
        user_agent=app/name,redirect_uri='http://localhost')
auth_uri = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
print(auth_uri)
credentials=FLOW.step2_exchange(code)

print(credentials)    

storage = Storage('log2.json')
storage.put(credentials)
credentials = storage.get()


print(credentials)
f=open("log2.json","r")
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

f.read only gives me user basic information , how do i read user emails?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to read their emails or do you just want the users email address?   https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get should return the users email address if you send 'me' as the user id.

Comment: i want to read their emails

Comment: Then you should be going through the Gmail api don't you think